# Memory consumption when running multiple copies of a process on a UNIX AIX server

Tags: unix, aix

On a UNIX AIX server if I start multiple copies of the same process will memory be allocated for the code, data and stack for each copy of the process ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the process is not designed to work with multiple copies of itself. There are programs which recognize that they're already running and share objects. Completely isolated programs will all run for themselves.

What program are we talking about?